# Are the hadith which portray that having anal sex with your wife is haram, unreliable?

Tags: authenticity, sex

Do not enter your women in their behinds"
(Jami at Tirmidhi-1166)

"Allah will not look at a man who enters a man or a woman in the behind.”
(Tirmidhi)

"He who has intercourse with his wife through her anus is accursed"(Abu-Dawud)

"Allah is not too shy to tell the truth” three times. “Do not have intercourse with women in their back passages"
(Ibn Majah and Musnad Ahmed)

Do other scholars consider these narrators reliable? Are those who judged these narrators as weak narrators, incorrect?

It doesn't make sense to just accept hadith as authentic if scholars have said certain narrators in the chain are reliable? Are there known reliable hadith which have unreliable narrators?

Citing the opinion of scholars who say it's wrong, as an argument for it being wrong, isn't really an argument.

The following website linked here, in my opinion is trash and is flat incorrect about how they interpret the Qur'anic verse about entering your wives as you wish, being about anal sex. But there's a lot of valid arguments here regarding the hadith in question - I am unsure if they accurately portrayed the thoughts of the scholars in here.

https://cjislam.weebly.com/why-anal-sex-is-halal-in-islam-11-brilliant-points.html

Answer (score 1):

I will only deal with one of these ahadith. The common chain is:

> Aasim > Isa ibn Hittan > Muslim ibn Sallam > Ali ibn Talq: The Prophet (SAW) said: [...] Don't go to women from their behind, because Allah does not shy away from the truth.

Several people narrated this from Aasim.

Tirmidhi has the chain: Ahmad ibn Manee' > Hannad > Abu Muawiyah > Aasim.

This chain has weakness, but the good thing is we don't need to rely on it.

We also have the chain in the [Musnad of Ahmad](https://app.turath.io/book/25794?page=20078) and the Musannaf: [Ahmad >] Abdur-Razzaq > Ma'mar > Aasim.

Since Ahmad, Abdur-Razzaq, and Ma'mar are all extremely reliable, we do not need to worry about the weakness of Tirmidhi's connection to Aasim. This hadith definitely does come from Aasim.

The narrators of the chain from the Prophet (SAW) downwards are generally acceptable until Aasim.

We do not even need to completely rely on Aasim for this hadith because this hadith is supported by others from Muslim ibn Sallam, like his son Abdul-Malik through a reliable chain. ([Ilal Tirmidhi 40](https://app.turath.io/book/13131?page=57))

As for Aasim, he was weakened by Yahya ibn Qattan for his memory. He said: "He was not a hafiz." This is relatively mild criticism. Hafiz means someone who is good in his memory and transmission.

But, others strengthened him for his memory. Sufyan said: "There are four huffaz among people" and mentioned Aasim among them.

Yahya ibn Qattan was known to be particularly (maybe even too) strict.

The article also mentions an incident about Aasim:

> Affan: Hammad ibn Salamah narrated to us: from Aasim al-Ahwal: Humaid narrated to me: from Anas: That Umar (RA) forbade [...].
>
> Hammad said: So, I told Humaid: Aasim narrated this to me. But, he did not recognize it (i.e. this hadith).

The article mistranslates the last sentence as "he did not even know him (i.e. Aasim)."

This does look a bit bad, since Humaid doesn't recognize something Aasim claims to narrate from him. However, it is important to note that Humaid did not deny this narration. He simply did not recognize or remember it.

And sure enough, Yahya ibn Qattan himself says about Humaid: When Humaid's tawaqquf (practice) on some of the hadith of Anas was gone, he started doubting about them. I used to ask him about things from the fatawa of al-Hasan and he used to say, "I forgot them."

So, Humaid not recognizing the hadith isn't as severe a criticism of Aasim as one might believe at first. He did forget things, especially ahadith from Anas.

(The above information about the narrators is all taken from Mizan al-I'tidal as the article was relying on it.)

So, what we have here is a chain with the only problem being one narrator who has been strengthened by many but criticized by one or two for not being the best in memory. Additionally, this narrator is supported by other chains. This is a textbook example of a hasan hadith. It cannot be considered completely weak, and it is acted on for law.

That is why Tirmidhi grades the hadith Hasan in his collection.

Comment: This is a very sufficient answer. I want to be able to access the chains myself, how did you do this? I can't find any online resource, I'm not an Arabic speaker either but I'd at least use translation tools.

Comment: @SaA To access the chains, you really need to learn to read Arabic. The writer of the article was probably also using translation tools to access, and that is probably one of the reasons he misinterpreted the sentence he misinterpreted. Translation tools should be avoided.

Comment: My best friend is an Arab speaker. I feel a bit too concerned by how poor the translation tools will be so I'd also prefer to avoid it. Please can you send the site? I have some other general questions about the Qira'at discussed in hadith literature. Kind Regards